# Julia - MLJ - ERROR: UndefVarError: train_test_pair not defined

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and currently trying the [MLJ](https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/MLJ.jl) package. More precisely, I try to use some resampling strategy outside of the `evaluate` functions.

However the following simple lines :

```
using MLJ

cv = CV()
train_test_pairs(cv, 100)
```

raise `ERROR: UndefVarError: train_test_pairs not defined`

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I think it's because the `train_test_pairs` methods are not exported by the package, is that correct? If yes, what is the rationale behind this choice?

Answer (score 2):

`train_test_pairs` is a function from `MLJBase`.
Try

```
using MLJBase
using MLJ

cv = CV()
MLJBase.train_test_pairs(cv, 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

The API has changed and now the correct code is:

```
using MLJBase
using MLJ

cv = CV()
MLJBase.train_test_pairs(cv, 1:100)
```

If you rather need randomized shuffling for an example:

```
cv = CV(nfolds=5, shuffle=true, rng=0)
```